get response from the HTTP triggered azure function without part processing
i have a time triggered function and another function with http trigger who are hosted in the same azure function. I want to raise a http request to the http triggered function from the time triggered function. Also i don't want my time triggered function to wait for the http triggered function to complete. As it is a high processing time consuming task and the http triggered function can run independently. I just want to know how to handle this scenario.
one way i was thinking to return the request prematurely with the message "Function is running".i tried using async programming but with no success can you tell the way other way to handle it.

Please share your function code @AkashSingh

actually you can take a general code of azure function one with the timer trigger and another with http trigger due to confidentiality constraint i cannot share the code

How many triggers you are using? Total 3 (timer, 1 http trigger, 2 http trigger)?

You are calling http trigger from timer trigger function?

YES I AM CALLING A HTTP TRIGGERED FUNCTION FROM TIMERTRIGGERED FUNCTION

You can achieve it by using asyncio. I have used sample code of timer trigger and http trigger function and invoked http trigger function from timer trigger function.
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import aiohttp
import asyncio

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
async def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    await asyncio.sleep(70)

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )

@app.timer_trigger(schedule="* * * * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=False,
              use_monitor=False) 
async def timer_trigger(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    
    if myTimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed.')

    # Define the URL for the HTTP-triggered function
    url = "http://localhost:7071/api/http_trigger"

    # Define the asynchronous request
    async def trigger_http_function():
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
            async with client.get(url) as response:
                logging.info(f"Triggered HTTP function with status: {response.status}")

    asyncio.create_task(trigger_http_function())

    logging.info('HTTP request sent, not waiting for completion.')

I am getting expected response. Timer trigger function completes without waiting for http trigger function's completion.
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5907 Commit hash: N/A +807e89766a92b14fd07b9f0bc2bea1d8777ab209 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875

[2024-08-28T07:01:24.491Z] 0.02s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
[2024-08-28T07:01:24.494Z] 0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
[2024-08-28T07:01:24.495Z] 0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
[2024-08-28T07:01:24.496Z] 0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
[2024-08-28T07:01:24.579Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        http_trigger:  http://localhost:7071/api/http_trigger

        timer_trigger: timerTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-08-28T07:01:29.499Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000000D2022A4'.
[2024-08-28T07:02:00.027Z] Executing 'Functions.timer_trigger' (Reason='Timer fired at 2024-08-28T12:32:00.0023600+05:30', Id=8bc317c7-1900-4c8a-8a41-bb1f704673ca)
[2024-08-28T07:02:00.081Z] HTTP request sent, not waiting for completion.
[2024-08-28T07:02:00.081Z] Python timer trigger function executed.
[2024-08-28T07:02:00.101Z] Executed 'Functions.timer_trigger' (Succeeded, Id=8bc317c7-1900-4c8a-8a41-bb1f704673ca, Duration=89ms)
[2024-08-28T07:02:00.412Z] Executing 'Functions.http_trigger' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=7478e2d9-ab52-4c4a-a9e4-74349167c196)
[2024-08-28T07:02:00.426Z] Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-08-28T07:03:00.023Z] Executing 'Functions.timer_trigger' (Reason='Timer fired at 2024-08-28T12:33:00.0234478+05:30', Id=6f654043-89dc-4583-bdf1-e21a1b23e123)
[2024-08-28T07:03:00.029Z] Python timer trigger function executed.
[2024-08-28T07:03:00.029Z] HTTP request sent, not waiting for completion.
[2024-08-28T07:03:00.030Z] Executed 'Functions.timer_trigger' (Succeeded, Id=6f654043-89dc-4583-bdf1-e21a1b23e123, Duration=6ms)
[2024-08-28T07:03:00.292Z] Executing 'Functions.http_trigger' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=0051b829-9544-40de-85da-a45c1ab0e4a3)
[2024-08-28T07:03:00.297Z] Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-08-28T07:03:10.442Z] Executed 'Functions.http_trigger' (Succeeded, Id=7478e2d9-ab52-4c4a-a9e4-74349167c196, Duration=70034ms)

Portal-


Is there a way, i can get to know the trigger function has started.A kind of acknowledgement in the timer trigger that the request is received and it will start processing

@AkashSingh Yes, You can see the logs you will get Executing http trigger function

No i want the response in the time trigger function like a status code or something

@AkashSingh please share one example or your code what you are trying to achieve

is it possible to do it like getting a intermediate respose from the http triggered function for this case?

@AkashSingh Your primary requirements was to let the timer trigger function completes without waiting for the http trigger's completion. This is what achieved by the given code. I am not sure what do you mean by getting an immediate response as in? Specify clearly
